# Valgrind and ScalaTest

Tags: scala, valgrind, scalatest

We want to use valgrind to detect memory leaks from one of our libraries. The library is written in scala and has a suite of ScalaTest libraries associated with it. If we run all the tests against the ScalaTest runner on the command line, everything passes. However, if we run them under valgrind to detect any memory leaks, then we see segfaults.

It always segfaults, and if you run it 5 times, if segfaults in 5 different places, usually deep inside the scala library.

Any ideas appreciated.

Comment: You are aware that scala uses the JVM?

Comment: yes of course. Is that a problem?